# Xamarin.Forms - Only rendering necessary datagrid rows in scroll view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagrid

I have an issue where the devices we need to test on (as these will be used in production) are beginning to have a huge performance hit at around 200 rows.. And we need to get to roughly ~800 rows without any major performance hits...

I've got a general idea of what the issue is, as the devices aren't really the fastest, I am just assuming that all of the rows are being rendered in the DataGrid (that is scrollable). Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to only render x amount of rows above and below the current position of the scroll view against the DataGrid?

I have looked around but haven't found any questions or answers about this specific question, so I'm sorry if I've missed it and this quesiton has been asked.

Comment: At first, you should be more precise about the control you use. The framework doesn't contain any control named DataGrid out of the box: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-controls#views-that-display-collections
Secondly, you have to be sure that your control is using Recycling.
Can you share some code ?

Comment: Guess some videos from David or Gerald mentioning "xamarin forms collection infinite scroll" would help